# NSDataDetector more accuracy (ignore time only)

Tags: objective-c

NSDataDetector is very handy to find different types of dates within a string. (e.g. 2015-03-10 or 10. March 15). This is great but how can I tell NSDataDetector to ignore time patterns only (e.g. "Whatever my text is 2:33 and so on"). NSDataDetector recognises this as  - TODAY 2:33

In other words: Can I force NSDataDetector to find full dates only ?

Thanks,
Sascha

Comment: Well ... now I used one of my DTS Tickets for this. Maybe an Apple Developer has an idea. I let you know.

Comment: FYI: Apple answered and it's not possible as intended. They told me to file a bugreport (feature request). I'll do so.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to run some post processing. Once you have extracted the list of date found. Loop through each result. Locate the original text used to identify the text and check if the text match your format for instance always a year etc. You can then ignore any of the non full date format.

I am actually looking for the same but could not find anything useful directly built by Apple. Then I come up with this idea. Not idea, but should do the job.